# RDP running VERY slow to local server

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, windows-server-2012

We use Azure VM's without issue. I remote into them just fine.

We set up a local server on the same network as our office, running server 2012, quad core, 16GB ram etc.

For some reason, RDP runs very slow from my desktop PC, but not on my colleagues right next to me.

My PC --->  Azure VM (Works just fine)

My PC --->  VPN ---> Clients servers (Works just fine)

My PC --->  Local Server (Very slow and freezes)

Other Local PC ---> Local Server (Works just fine)

I cannot work out what could be causing these issues.

I have reinstalled my graphics driver, as well as put all settings on the lowest possible. No change.

Comment: Seems to happen more when I do something like close a window, or move a window in RDP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

> navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters 
>   and make a new DWORD value called DisableTaskOffload and then set it's value to 1.

(from http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/remote-desktop-is-fast-on-one-computer-and-very/38b4cea9-adcc-4f5a-9103-ec3e3e3b0006)

Comment: Thank you, although this is something I have tried before and has no effect.

Comment: Is there a reason this was marked as the answer even though it didn't resolve the problem?